# if() doesn't print out json data unless I use var_dump in php

Tags: php, json, parsing

```
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json_output = json_decode($json, TRUE);
var_dump($json_output);
if($json_output){
    echo "TRUE";
} else {
    echo "FALSE";
}
```

the data from var_dump($json_output) is

```
boolean true
```

followed by `TRUE` from my if statement unless I remove var_dump($json_output), then nothing happens and TRUE does not get printed out either. Why does this happen?

Comment: Could you echo `$json`? You're asking for an associative array back (`json_decode($json, TRUE);`) so I'd expect you'd need to be checking the boolean value of `$json_output[0]` rather than the whole array

Answer (score 1):

One could ascertain that when you removed the `var_dump` line you committed an editing mistake, which caused a syntax error (or the like) and since you have error reporting turned off, you don't see any output.

**`var_dump` does not affect the value of a variable and, therefore, does not affect its conduct in a conditional.**

```
$json = json_encode(true);
$json_output = json_decode($json, TRUE);
//var_dump($json_output);
if($json_output){
    echo "TRUE";
} else {
    echo "FALSE";
}

// output: TRUE
```

Comment: +1 for boldness! You're probably right, as I don't really see any other explanation, but I love that you conclude with certainty that the OP somehow screwed up the deletion of a single line :)